# Check Two Different Rows, but Same Column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get Excel to look at two different rows in two different sheets but the same column to validate the movement of the numbers in a separate column.
How can I get rid of the current loop that I have so that it reduces the loading time? Because as of now it takes **too** long. 
Also, I know that I should not be using loops, I used it in low hopes that it would work, just as fine

```
Sub repeatingrows()

Dim oldsheet As Worksheet
Dim newsheet As Worksheet
Set newsheet = Application.ActiveSheet

Set oldsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
Set newsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)


'CHECK IF THE ROWS ARE SIMILAIR TO PREVIOUS SHEET

Dim rrow As Integer
Dim srow As Integer

For rrow = 3 To 397
    For srow = 3 To 397
        If oldsheet.Cells(rrow, 2) = newsheet.Cells(srow, 2) Then
            If oldsheet.Cells(rrow, 5) = newsheet.Cells(srow, 5) Then
                If oldsheet.Cells(rrow, 6) = newsheet.Cells(srow, 6) Then
                    With newsheet
                        oldsheet.Range(oldsheet.Cells(rrow, 16), oldsheet.Cells(rrow, 19)).Copy
                        .Range(.Cells(srow, 16), .Cells(srow, 19)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
                    End With '^COPY AND PASTES THE ROW
                Else
                End If
            Else
            End If
        Else
        End If
    Next srow
Next rrow

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `worksheetfunction.match` or an array for comparison.

Comment: Instead of using nested `if`'s you could combine all statements into one using `And` operator.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav is that instead of the loop and the ifs or just the if's?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Not big optimization, it is AND operator in vba

Comment: @MichałTurczyn, except that VBA does **not** shortcut AND evaluation. Combining all the `If` statements into one big one forces evaluation of all 3 conditions every time. Having them as separate statements allows code to skip evaluation of 1 or 2 `If`s if any of the earlier ones are `False`. Minor savings, but a savings to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of objects!
Accessing object members can be time consuming. Writing to objects worst. So you can cache read and writes, and get big time. Also, avoid copy/past, use .Value=...

```
Sub repeatingrows()

    Dim oldsheet As Worksheet
    Dim newsheet As Worksheet
    Set newsheet = Application.ActiveSheet

    Set oldsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
    Set newsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

    Dim oldv, newv, c

    'CHECK IF THE ROWS ARE SIMILAIR TO PREVIOUS SHEET

    Dim rrow As Integer
    Dim srow As Integer

    oldv = oldsheet.Range(oldsheet.Cells(1, 1), oldsheet.Cells(397, 19))
    newv = newsheet.Range(newsheet.Cells(1, 1), newsheet.Cells(397, 19))

    For rrow = 3 To 397
        For srow = 3 To 397
            If oldv(rrow, 2) = newv(srow, 2) And oldv(rrow, 5) = newv(srow, 5) And oldv(rrow, 6) = newv(srow, 6) Then
                For c = 16 To 19 'can't use range1.Value = range2.Value in VB arrays
                    newv(srow, c) = newv(srow, c) + oldv(rrow, c)
                Next
            End If
        Next
    Next

    'Finally, write results
    newsheet.Range(oldsheet.Cells(1, 1), oldsheet.Cells(397, 19)) = newv

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much,I was about to make the arrays completely different. The only thing is that it is saying Method ' Range' of  objject  ' _Worksheet' failed. Specifically for the `newv = newsheet.Range(oldsheet.Cells(1, 1), oldsheet.Cells(397, 19))`

Comment: Yeah, when I took a good look at it again, I just saw it. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the program you have to store data from two sheets to two arrays. Then all the logic you will do using cached arrays, instead of referreing to the value of cells thousands of times (that's quite "expensive" operation).